# (PHP) How to find words beginning with a pattern and replace all of them?

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I have a string. An example might be "Contact /u/someone on reddit, or visit /r/subreddit or /r/subreddit2"

I want to replace any instance of "/r/x" and "/u/x" with "`[/r/x](http://reddit.com/r/x)`" and "`[/u/x](http://reddit.com/u/x)`" basically.

So I'm not sure how to 1) find "/r/" and then expand that to the rest of the word (until there's a space), then 2) take that full "/r/x" and replace with my pattern, and most importantly 3) do this for all "/r/" and "/u/" matches in a single go...

The only way I know to do this would be to write a function to walk the string, character by character, until I found "/", then look for "r" and "/" to follow; then keep going until I found a space. That would give me the beginning and ending characters, so I could do a string replacement; then calculate the new end point, and continue walking the string.

This feels... dumb. I have a feeling there's a relatively simple way to do this, and I just don't know how to google to get all the relevant parts.

Comment: Have you tried to use `regex` ?

Comment: You should look at the concept called regular expressions (regex). It works the same way in several languages

Comment: My knowledge of regex is very basic. I see a suggested answer that gives a suggestion for a regex that might work. I didn't realize a regex might be possible for this. Truly regex is a nightmare. I mean, amazing. It's amazing. Totally not a nightmare. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `preg_replace` will [do what you want](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Try:

```
$string = preg_replace('#(/(?:u|r)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)#', '[\1](http://reddit.com\1)', $string);
```

Here is an example: http://ideone.com/dvz2zB

You should see if you can discover what characters are valid in a Reddit name or in a Reddit username and modify the `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` charset accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. I didn't realize a regex could do what I was trying to do. I knew regexes could be amazing, but yeesh.

Comment: I saw that you think regex is a nightmare. I remember when I was trying to learn it and I discovered it's not actually that bad. Discover by doing. Here's my regex in an online regex tool I find invaluable. It explains all the components when you hover over parts of the regex string: http://regexr.com/3a3l1

Comment: Had to add a closing paren like so:

$string = preg_replace('#(/(?:u|r)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)#', '[\1](http://reddit.com\1)', $string);

Absolutely worked, and thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion regex would be an overkill for such a simple operation. If you just want to replace instance of "/r/x" with `"[r/x](http://reddit.com/r/x)"` and "/u/x" with `"[/u/x](http://reddit.com/u/x)"` you should use `str_replace` although with preg_replace it'll lessen the code.

```
str_replace("/r/x","[/r/x](http://reddit.com/r/x)","whatever_string");
```

use regex for intricate search string and replace. you can also use http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php regular expression generator if you have something complex to capture in the string.

Comment: The example expresses that the part after the `/r/` or `/u/` is variable and is a perfect example for regex.

Comment: what variable? maybe i missed that in the question. =/

Comment: It's implied with his example string that he has `"Contact /u/someone on reddit, or visit /r/subreddit or /r/subreddit2"` and then referencing it simply with `/r/x` where `x` is the variable.

Comment: My apologies for not expressing this well - I tend to be verbose, so I was trying to not be verbose, and went too far. Indeed, it has to match a variable. The regex solutions that a couple have shown are perfect, and greatly expanded my understanding of regex. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a regular expression.

A basic pattern starts out as a fixed string. `/u/` or `/r/` which would match those exactly.  This can be simplified to match one or another with `/(?:u|r)/` which would match the same as those two patterns.  Next you would want to match everything from that point up to a space.  You would use a negative character group `[^ ]` which will match any character that is not a space, and apply a modifier, `*`, to match as many characters as possible that match that group. `/(?:u|r)/[^ ]*`

You can take that pattern further and add a lookbehind, `(?<= )` to ensure your match is preceded by a space so you're not matching a partial which results in `(?<= )/(?:u|r)/[^ ]*`.  You wrap all of that to make a capturing group `((?<= )/(?:u|r)/[^ ]*)`.  This will capture the contents within the parenthesis to allow for a replacement pattern.  You can express your chosen replacement using the `\1` reference to the first captured group as `[\1](http://reddit.com\1)`.

In php you would pass the matching pattern, replacement pattern, and subject string to the `preg_replace` function.

Comment: When I can upvote, I will upvote this answer. Thank you for the amazingly helpful explanation. I am significantly less afraid (terrified?) of regex after that. Awesome.

Comment: What was said in a comment on another answer, it is intimidating to get started with. Learning by doing is a great way. Understanding the terminology and what the uses are for will help, then you can figure out what to search for to discover the syntax.